# Updating div after Parse query for more objects

Tags: php, ajax, parse-platform

I am loading a group of objects (21 initial) on page load via php include file, and want to use ajax to call the file and get a larger number of posts. Currently, I am checking if a $count = $_POST['newCount'] is greater than 0. If not it loads initially 21 posts, otherwise use the new count to get more posts. When a button is clicked call the file via ajax and on success reload that div section.

I have been able to call the file and get the initial 21 posts, and echo the new count back to me and reload a div, but if I uncomment the actual query call the file does not seem to run.

in php file:

```
if ($count == 0)
{
    $myPostsQuery = new ParseQuery('posts');
    try{
        $myPostsQuery->equalTo("postOwnerId", $objId);
        $myPostsQuery->limit(21); // limit to at most 10 results
        $myPostsQuery->descending("createdAt");
        $myPostsResults = $myPostsQuery->find();
    } catch (ParseException $ex) {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a ParseException with an error code and message.
      echo $ex;
    }
} else {
    $myPostsQueryNew = new ParseQuery('posts');
    try{
        $myPostsQueryNew->equalTo("postOwnerId", $objId);
        $myPostsQueryNew->limit($count); // limit to at most 10 results
        $myPostsQueryNew->descending("createdAt");
        $myPostsResults = $myPostsQueryNew->find();
    } catch (ParseException $ex) {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a ParseException with an error code and message.
          echo $ex;
    }
}
```

in main file:

```
        <?php 
              include('getMyPosts.php');
        ?>
        <div class="posts detailsContain" id="myPosts">
            <?php 
                foreach ($myPostsResults as $postResult) {
                    $pic = $postResult->get("pic");
                    $postObjId = $postResult->getObjectId();
            ?>
                    <div class="postHolder"><a href="post.php?postID=<?=$postObjId?>"><img src="images/transparent.png" style="background-image:url(<?=$pic->getURL()?>);" alt="post image"></a></div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

ajax setup on main file

```
$('#loadMoreForm').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'getMyPosts.php',
                    data: ($('#loadMoreForm').serialize()),
                    success: function (html) {
                        var countNew = parseInt($('#postsCountLoad').attr('value')) + 21;
                        $('#postsCountLoad').val(countNew);
                        $('#moreText').html(html); //using this to confirm new count updates to send next time
                        $("#myPosts").load(location.href + " #myPosts");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: You need to specify a `LIMIT offset, count` so like `LIMIT $page*21, 21` as you have 21 items per page, so you need to know which page in your pagination you want to get

Comment: You mean on the area I am reloading? My assumption in this setup is the div would reload with all the posts, current and new. I am not putting any pagination in